# PHP code in Variable?

Tags: php, variables, include

I want to apply some php to a variable and wondering how to do this. I am adapting a piece of code written [PHP opening closing times](http://coryetzkorn.com/blog/php-store-hours-plugin/) and would like to change it. Essentially I want the below code to work...

```
$open_output = '

<span class="label"><?php echo $text_qty; ?></span>

      <input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" id="qty"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
      <a id="button-cart" class="button" title="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>"><span><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></a> ';
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

The full code can be found in the resource.

Comment: You can't nest `<?php ?>` tags.Use a double-quoted string, and just put the variables in.

Comment: Read [the PHP manual on string quoting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate strings & variables together

```
$open_output = '<span class="label">'.$text_qty.'</span>
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="'.$minimum.'" id="qty"/>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="'.$product_id.'" />
<a id="button-cart" class="button" title="'.$button_cart.'"><span>'.$button_cart.'</span></a> ';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not right, but you can execute php code with `eval('?>'. $open_output)`. You can load the template from a file on the variable, with `get_file_contents()` function and execute it with `eval()`.

Comment: is it possible to somehow stop the execution of a PHP code, and start another process and compute a string that one can bring back in the initial code and run with 'eval' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$open_output = <<< EOF
<span class="label"><?php echo $text_qty; ?></span>
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $minimum; ?>" id="qty"/>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" size="2" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
<a id="button-cart" class="button" title="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>"><span><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></a>
EOF;
echo $open_output;
```

remove the space between < and EOF.